# Boostrap not creating 4 columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is probably an easy one, but I'm new to bootstrap and aren't quite familiar with how it works.  I have the following code to create 4 even-width columns in a row. But it keeps showing up as 4 vertically stacked columns on my laptop (1920x1080) and I'm not quite sure where I'm doing it wrong.

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-3"><!--about us feature 1st -->
                    <div class="about-block">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h6>AVAILABILITY</h6>
                            <p>Fast Response Time<br> 15 Minutes Setup</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--about us feature 1st closed -->
                <div class="col-md-3"><!--about us feature 2nd -->
                    <div class="about-block">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h6>SPEED</h6>
                            <p>Average 7x Faster<br> Complete Data Coverage</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--about us feature 2nd closed -->
                <div class="col-md-3"><!--about us feature 3rd -->
                    <div class="about-block">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h6>SAFETY</h6>
                            <p>Reduce Human Risk<br> No Scaffolding</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--about us feature 3rd closed -->
                <div class="col-md-3"><!--about us feature 4th -->
                    <div class="about-block">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h6>COST SAVINGS</h6>
                            <p>Targeted Repairs<br> Less Outage Time</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--about us feature 4th closed -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE** Added screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Shows as 4 columns on a single line for me (on my desktop). Maybe take a screenshot to show us?

Comment: Please post your css too.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help! I found the problem to be that the default bootstrap css local file was overridden to change the behavior of how the columns are displayed.  Solved it by updating the bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-sm-3` instead, or make your `<div>` element wider. If you are using a container directly inside body, you shouldn't have any problem. If you are using inside another element, make sure it is wide enough.

Comment: Can't see any problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20621/ . Double your screen resolution and send screenshot for us.

Comment: from your link, it is showing 1 vertically stacked column, which is my problem.  What I really want is 4 columns in one row.

Comment: If you don't give us more information, we'll not be able to help you. Everyone sees 4 columns side by side.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my localhost. The link you provided shows the exact same thing as the screenshot. I'm starting to wonder if this is more of my computer issue rather than the code?

Comment: I can't double my resolution. It's already max out at 1920x1080.

Comment: I see now. There is probably another css or another HTML element that is changing this behavior. Could you show us more of your HTML?

Comment: Sure. I didn't write this original code, but I'll try look through and post more where I think can affect that.  On the other hand though, I've cut down the code to just include columns and texts on https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20621/#&togetherjs=gssVLdiPLy. Since that is not using anything from my computer, any idea how that is still showing up differently for me than anyone else?

Comment: Actually, jsfiddle is working. The display window was just too small. Let me post the css and html.

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing `row-fluid` class to `style="float: left"`. Second, it is true that (in theory) the screen is divided into 12, but 3*4 might be more than 12 (margin, border, etc.). If the first part renders three columns and the 4th underneath, try reducing the size of the columns by setting, for instance, width=24%.

Comment: I tried style="float: left". It became left aligned instead of center aligned. But it is still showing 1 column with 4 blocks vertically stacked instead of 4 columns in one row.

Comment: Did you try setting the style to the outer div?